# Why some binaries don't work with shell_exec?

Tags: php, fedora

I don't understand why, but I can't execute some binaries from a PHP page.

If I call this from a PHP page, I don't get any output:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/which ffmpeg');
```

If I execute it from CLI, it works:

```
$ sudo -u apache php -r 'echo shell_exec("/usr/bin/which ffmpeg");'
/usr/bin/ffmpeg
```

But if I try to call `whereis` instead of `which` from a PHP page, I do get an output although they are in the same directory:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec('/usr/bin/whereis ffmpeg');
```

I don't understand the logic behind...

---

I've verified the file permissions, and everything seems fine: `-rwxr-xr-x. root:root`, and there's is no ACL.

I'm using Fedora 28 (SELinux is set to permissive). These commands work on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: have you tried echo shell_exec('sudo /usr/bin/which ffmpeg');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `which` command will generate the output on `STDOUT`, when the program is found, but it will use `STDERR` when there is no such command.

```
$ strace which php
[...]
access("/usr/bin/php", R_OK)            = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "/usr/bin/php\n", 13) = 13
[...]
```

Notice the `1` at `write()`, which is the handler for `STDOUT`, but when the command is not found, a different handler is used:

```
$ strace which something_not_existing
[...]
stat("/usr/games/bin/something_not_existing", 0x7ffc20f046a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "which: no something_not_existing"..., 150) = 150
[...]
```

Notice the `2` at `write()`, which is the handler for `STDERR`.

In the console, you will see both the output from `STDOUT` and the output from `STDERR`, but `shell_exec()` will only output/return the `STDOUT` stream.

Check http://www.php.net/shell_exec on how to capture the `STDERR` stream as well. You might even want to use other execution functions like `proc_open()` to control the `STDIN`/`STDOUT`/`STDERR` streams, depending on your requirement.

The `whereis` command will always write to `STDOUT`, thats because you see the output in php via `shell_exec()`.

Comment: You're right, and that's the right answer to my question. Executing `shell_exec('which ffmpeg 2>&1')` clearly shows that ffmpeg could not be found.